# feel to be under pressure

Tags: word-choice

Look at the clause in bold:

> Job burnout is a state of physical, emotional, and mental exhaustion
>   which happens due to long-term exposure to a demanding job. It is also
>   a response to acute job-related pressures. It is a psychological
>   syndrome that involves emotional exhaustion, depersonalization, and
>   low personal accomplishment. In emotional exhaustion, **the afflicted
>   person feels being under pressure and losing emotional resources**,
>   while in depersonalization, a person becomes indifferent to his/her
>   clients.

For sure I know the words "being" and "losing" are wrong. But what about using "to be" after "feel"? Would

> In emotional exhaustion, **the afflicted person feels to be under
>   pressure and to lose emotional resource**

be correct?

Comment: Your text is defective English, so it's not really worth trying to deconstruct the syntax. Or the semantics, come to that - it's anybody's guess what exactly the writer means when he refers to someone *feeling that they are losing emotional resources*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about an incompetently-written sentence

Comment: I'm not sure that the sentence is wrong but it needs more context

Comment: Ok anybody, let me bring more context:"Job burnout is a state of physical, emotional, and mental exhaustion which happens due to long-term exposure to a demanding job. It is also a response to acute job-related pressures. It is a psychological syndrome that involves emotional exhaustion, depersonalization, and low personal accomplishment. In emotional exhaustion, the afflicted person feels being under pressure and losing emotional resources, while in depersonalization, a person becomes indifferent to his/her clients.

Comment: "...feels under pressure and loses emotional resources..." seems like much clearer wording. "Feels being under pressure" I guess is technically not wrong, but it sure sounds ugly.

Comment: [_Under pressure_](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/under+pressure). Typical, a person _is/was_ under pressure. I don't think there is anything wrong with "feels under pressure" but something in me want to say "feels **like** he/she is under pressure". Also, I don't see a problem with "In emotional exhaustion, the afflicted person **feels pressure** and **loses** emotional resources".

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for single word

1.'Stangulation' can be a choice .

The afflicted person feels strangulated and ......

2.Suffocation

The afflicted person feels suffocated and ...

Otherwise,if you are asking about the usage of the phrase..then feels  to be under pressure in the given sentence is not wrong.
Or

'Feels like being under pressure' can be used instead i think.

Comment: I don't think that is what the questioner is looking for.